# Facebook Graph API V2.2 Comments Return Empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have been searching the similar posts of my issue, however, I couldn't find out the helpful answer so far.

I am trying to retrieve the comments as well as the comment's reply with the latest API version.

I am calling the official URL which is https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/863033393748810/comments , however, it returns me an empty data. I am concerned that I have given the permission in my code.

I have used the "/posts" however, that doesn't help me to retrieve the comment's replies, so I wanted to use "/comments".

I appreciate your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such endpoint for the pages object. Any posts to the page (fan/owner) must be retrieved through `/posts`

Comment: there is a resource from facebook which is explaining as "https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/03/new-apis-for-comment-replies/"  however, it doesn't work.

Comment: any response in regards?

Comment: @mehmetaltuntas that information is correct, the object id there is a page post not a page. You can view the comments of a page post by requesting object-id/comments

Comment: that also consists of the reply of the comments? ta

Answer (score 0):

You can try {pageId}_{postId} format instead of just using postId for this endpoint and you can test your url on [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Your url will return like this  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{POSTID}_863033393748810/comments